# Remotely accessing the openfire installed on fedora machine

Tags: linux, fedora, xmpp, openfire

HI ,

I have installed Openfire on fedora machine. i can start the openfire on this machine and it runs on the localhost. But i can not access openfire remotly as follows

http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9090

i have desabled ip tables on this computer

also when i do telnet for port 9090 on the localhost , it works

could some one help me to get this working

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: *I have disabled iptables.*

Answer (score 1):

Edit conf/openfire.xml to use a port on a host or IP other than localhost.

1st result for Google: `openfire conf`.

Comment: Hi mcandre , could you tell me , where should i add this ip address. openfire.xml

Comment: here is the openfire.xml http://pastebin.com/9bUSkvny , it has only the port no , but there is no local ipaddress thought it works on localhost,

Comment: i did edit the location network interface by giving the relevant ip address , but still can not connect remotely